# How can I write an equation with two curly brackets?

Tags: eqnarray

I am trying to write this equation.

[image]

I used these commands:

```
\begin{eqnarray}\label{eqn1}
|1, \:\: \:1\rangle &=& \uparrow \uparrow   \nonumber \\
|1, \:\:\: 0\rangle &=& \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\big(\uparrow \downarrow + \downarrow\uparrow \big) \\
|1, -1\rangle &=& \downarrow \downarrow   \nonumber \\ \nonumber
\end{eqnarray}
```

But how can I add the two curly brackets?

Comment: Don't use  `eqnarray` – it has bad spacing. For the brackets, you can see the answers to {https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/229253/adding-braces-around-equations/229263#229263}.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about this?
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \label{eqn1}
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}
  \left\{
\begin{array}{lcl}
|1, \phantom{-}1\rangle &{}={}& \uparrow \uparrow \\
|1, \phantom{-}0\rangle &=& \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\big(\uparrow \downarrow + \downarrow\uparrow \big) \\
|1, -1\rangle &=& \downarrow \downarrow 
\end{array}
\right\}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If it's desired to have the rightmost digits within the `|...\rangle` aligned, that can be accomplished by using `\phantom{$-$}` rather than approximating the width by spaces.

Comment: @barbarabeeton, Yes. You are right.

Comment: @modnar: The spacing around `=` is wider than usual.

Comment: @Werner, Thanks for pointing it out. It's fixed.

Comment: @modnar: `1.5pt` is not the correct width. You should rather `\setlength{arraycolsep}{0pt}` and then use `{}={}` as it will set the appropriate `\mathrel` space.

Answer (score 7):

Never use `eqnarray`.

Your particular alignment can be obtained with `alignedat`; the argument `2` means that we want two pairs of right/left aligned columns. We leave empty the right aligned columns so to emulate two left aligned columns.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\foo}[2]{\mathopen|{#1}\ {#2}\rangle}
\newcommand{\uua}{{\uparrow}{\uparrow}}
\newcommand{\uda}{{\uparrow}{\downarrow}}
\newcommand{\dua}{{\downarrow}{\uparrow}}
\newcommand{\dda}{{\downarrow}{\downarrow}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{eqn1}
\left\{
\begin{alignedat}{2}
  &\foo{1}{1}  &&= \uua \\
  &\foo{1}{0}  &&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\bigl(\uda + \dua\bigr) \\
  &\foo{1}{-1} &&= \dda
\end{alignedat}
\right\}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Choose a better name for `\foo`, based on the name of the symbol. All the braces I used in the definitions are important.

[image]

As an aside, avoid labeling like `eqn1`: use a string that describes the equation.

You may want `\tfrac` instead of `\frac` and the output would be

[image]

If you need combinations of the arrows (any number of them), you can use

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\foo}[2]{\mathopen|{#1}\ {#2}\rangle}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\AR}{m}
 {
  \str_map_inline:nn { #1 }
   {
    \str_case:nn { ##1 } { {u}{{\uparrow}} {d}{{\downarrow}} }
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{eqn1}
\left\{
\begin{alignedat}{2}
  &\foo{1}{1}  &&= \AR{uu} \\
  &\foo{1}{0}  &&= \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\bigl(\AR{ud} + \AR{du}\bigr) \\
  &\foo{1}{-1} &&= \AR{dd}
\end{alignedat}
\right\}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

The output is the same, but you can do

```
\[
\AR{u}\quad
\AR{d}\quad
\AR{uu}\quad
\AR{uduudd}
\]
```

to get

[image]

Answer (score 2):

With `Bmatrix*` defined in `mathtools`:

```
\documentclass[border=3.14,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{eqn1}
    \setlength\arraycolsep{1pt}
\begin{Bmatrix*}[r]
|1, & 1\rangle  =& \uparrow\uparrow & \\
|1, & 0\rangle  =& \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}& \!\bigl(\uparrow \downarrow + \downarrow\uparrow \bigr) \\
|1, & -1\rangle =& \downarrow\downarrow &
\end{Bmatrix*}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another idea it is to use `braket` package with newcommand to predefinite symbols of Table 142 of the documentation *The Comprehensive LATEX Symbol List* and with a style that it is similar to the first image: you see the packages

```
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
```

You will have:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{braket}

\newcommand{\uupa}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{$\rightleftarrows$}}
\newcommand{\dupa}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{$\leftrightarrows$}}
\begin{document}
\[\Set{\begin{array}{lcl}
\Ket{1, 1}  & = & \upuparrows\\
\Ket{1, 0}  & = & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\uupa+\dupa) \\
\Ket{1, -1}  & = & \downdownarrows 
\end{array}}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Remember that the `\Set` command give a bit of spaces to left and the right the curly bracket.

Comment: The name of the package really [is *"braket"*](https://mirror.las.iastate.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/braket/braket.pdf) (not *"bracket"*). Perhaps add an (authoritative) reference to it to make it more clear (by indirect means)? (But ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written right now.)

Comment: @PeterMortensen Hi Peter, I see braket and not bracket :-(..(in fact there is not an edit). Sometimes when I use this package I write bracket; but when I compile I find the error :-). I don't know what to write also because my English is limited and I have to use the translator. You are allowed to edit my answer if you prefer. Don't worry. My best regards.