# Increase the thickness of a brace

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, cases

I'd like to know if it's possible to increase the thickness of a brace.

**The code**

```
\documentclass[oneside]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\newcommand{\ve}{\textbf}
\newcommand{\veu}{\ve u}
\newcommand{\vev}{\ve v}

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
        \begin{cases}
            q_1(\veu) \land q_1(\vev) &= \begin{vmatrix}
                u_2 & v_2\\
                u_3 & v_3
            \end{vmatrix} = u_2v_3 - u_3v_2 = 0\\[1.5em]
            q_2(\veu) \land q_2(\vev) &= \begin{vmatrix}
                u_1 & v_1\\
                u_3 & v_3
            \end{vmatrix} = u_1v_3 - u_3v_1 = 0\\[1.5em]
            q_3(\veu) \land q_3(\vev) &= \begin{vmatrix}
                u_1 & v_1\\
                u_3 & v_3
            \end{vmatrix} = u_1v_3 - u_3v_1 = 0
        \end{cases}
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

**The result**

[image: screenshot]

I think the brace is a bit too thin, and I tried to replace `cases` with a manual `\left\{` but that didn't work.

Comment: Always post *full* minimal examples. Also `cases` already use `\left\{` so it will not help much.

Comment: @daleif I think I posted a full minimal example. There's the template at the top so that it does not have to be repeated two times.

Comment: @daleif If that's the case, I'll change my question to: "How to make a thicker brace?"

Comment: it wasn't there when I answered. And your example will never compile as you are using `amsmath` elements and `amsmath` is not loaded in your example. I would not bother with an issue like this. Braces look different in different fonts.

Comment: Still not compilable.

Comment: Just add `amsmath`. Short of writing your own brace using `tikz` I don't think it this is worth improving.

Comment: @daleif I'm sorry, I forgot about `amsmath`. I am using many packages, so I forgot about it. So are you saying there is nothing to do?

Comment: I'm saying it is not worth it. For most documents there are many other things that ought to be improved before one tackle an issue like this. BTW: why `\mathbf` and not `\bm` from the `bm` package? I personally like italic bold face better than upright bold face for vectors.

Comment: This answer, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/229253/adding-braces-around-equations/229254#229254, might give some ideas.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Very nice, thanks! I'll try to implement some of those solutions.

Comment: This answer by egreg, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35891/import-curly-brackets-from-mathdesign-utopia, also goes to the heart of it, though isn't quite the same as the earlier reference I gave.